# How to work around "Release file expired" problem on a local mirror

Tags: apt

I have a local mirror (created with debmirror), and when I run `apt-get update` after a few days, I get this:

```
E: Release file expired, ignoring file:/home/wena/.repo_bin/dists/sid/Release (invalid since 14h 31min 45s)
```

How do I work around that?

Comment: Security Warning: This question asks for a work around. However it is better to fix the mirror or point to a working one. I changed to point at http://httpredir.debian.org/debian and it started working again.

Comment: Switch to a different mirror and it'll work.

Comment: What is "better" depends on what your goals are. If your goal is to get the latest packages from Debian then changing mirror is the right soloution. If your goal is to use the older mirror that you have locally so you can get on with your work where Internet is unavailable or expensive then turning off the expiry check is the right solution. If your goal is to update to a specific older version of the repo for bug triage reasons then again turning off the expiry check is the right solution.

Comment: Indeed, I reached this message while using Debian Archive for a Debian Wheezy system that can't be updated.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Add this to the command:

```
-o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false
```

For example:

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

Comment: This worked, but some explanation of why it did would be useful.

Comment: This deactivates the check which verifies expired digital signatures, so apt will accept old and expired release keys as well.

Comment: Security Warning: This answer is a work around (as asked for). However it is better to fix the mirror or point to a working one. I changed to point at http://httpredir.debian.org/debian and it started working again.

Comment: you cannot switch that easily for already deprecated releases like say debian 6 where you need to use archives.debian.org to get any packages now

Comment: Does not work with Raspbian 10.

Answer (score 56):

If you do not care about this check, no matter for which mirror, just create a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` (e.g. name it `10no--check-valid-until`) and put the option directly in there:

```
Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "0";
```

After this, you will never be bothered again with the mentioned warning at all.

Comment: Although the workaround itself isn't the optimal solution, I have a development box that I don't care about, so this annoyance simply gets in my way. I was able to use this answer with Ansible since I can't find any way to add the accepted answer to the action module when using ansible_pkg_mgr.

Comment: one command: `echo "Acquire::Check-Valid-Until false;" | tee -a /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10-nocheckvalid
`

Comment: This is so good for legacy Dockerfiles. Stick this as the first line in a Dockerfile and all your problems go away. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

The release files have a valid-until entry, e.g. `Valid-Until: Thu, 07 Oct 2010 08:17:56 UTC`

If the release file isn't valid anymore, you should run debmirror again to check if there are any changes in the repository. One change will be the release file and you will get a new validity for it.

You could easily automate this with a crontab entry.

Comment: Thanks for that one. I should have looked inside that file before asking. Curiously though, is this a new thing? It didn't happen before (but once).

Comment: I don't use debian really often at the moment, but maybe they just changed the release file cycles to a shorter date...

Answer (score 8):

This can also happen if your system date/time is wrong. I fixed it by correcting my local time before doing the update.

Comment: So helpful. Ran into this on Windows 10 + WSL2... Wasn't clear from the error it was system clock dependent, but correcting local time was exactly what was needed.

Comment: SSL / TLS depends on (in principle) the correct time setting...

Answer (score 7):

Not sure whether its related with Jessie current issue (https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2019/03/msg00006.html) or not. but for those got a same error even already used

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

and still occurred a same issue, can try this instead

```
echo 'Acquire::Check-Valid-Until no;' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99no-check-valid-until
```

It works for me :)

Comment: Does not work with Raspbian 10....

Answer (score 4):

I removed `/var/lib/apt/*` and rerun `apt-get update`, and it works!

Comment: I do that for a completely different error, and it works for that one. This error is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Stupid error.... it still does not work with Raspbian 10

Answer (score 3):

Some of the mirrors out there might have stale files. This happened to me recently, and it was in also tied to the caching server I'm using (apt-cacher-ng) which tries to save bandwidth by redirecting the repositories for same archive to a single entity (in my case if was a Hungarian mirror). Direct updates through German mirror worked ok, for example. Try changing the mirror you're using. In case you're using apt-cacher-ng, you'll need to do something in the line of changing the following file's contents:

- /etc/apt-cacher-ng/backends_debian
- /etc/apt-cacher-ng/backends_debvol

After that you should also restart apt-cacher-ng for changes to take effect.

Comment: Note that I was asking for a workaround, not why this was happening (good answer though). In this case I was, knowingly, having a stale repository.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue on Windows WSL2 Ubuntu trying to spin up a docker container. I ran the command below on the CLI and it corrected the time mismatch.

```
sudo hwclock -s
```

Answer (score 1):

The mirror might not be expired.

Rather something else on your system might be messed up.  Try this:

---

1) Temporarily comment out related lines from from `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or `/etc/apt/source.list.d/*`. For example after I commented out the following two lines, my error went away, (with the consequence that these archives were temporarily not used for reloads):

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates non-free contrib main
deb http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
```

2) Open synaptic and reload, or probably `sudo apt-get update` would also work.

3) Comment these lines back in.

4) Repeat step 2.

---

Fixed this for me.  I'm guessing my apt cache got a bad date in it.

My problem occurred after restoring my / (root) and /var filesystems from btrfs snapshots to help fix a package install problem that occurred.  The exact error message that I was getting was:

> Release file for
>   http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/debian/dists/stretch-updates/InRelease
>   is expired (invalid since 5d 4h 50min 18s). Updates for this
>   repository will not be applied. Release file for
>   http://security.debian.org/dists/stretch/updates/InRelease is expired
>   (invalid since 2d 2h 52min 43s). Updates for this repository will not
>   be applied.

Answer (score 0):

please check BIOS/System time, you should have the same time