# Is there a way to get security updates for wheezy after EOL

Tags: debian, security, backports

I know the best solution would be to upgrade the server after Debian wheezy has reached End Of LIfe in May 2018, but is there a way to continue running an old wheezy instance and get some minimal updates still?

Maybe some external apt-sources, that still are getting maintained somewhere?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Extended, https://raphaelhertzog.com/2018/02/20/time-to-join-extended-long-term-support-for-debian-7-wheezy/?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As indicated by [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru), there is a way to get updated packages for Debian 7, through Freexian’s [Extended LTS](https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/). See also [Raphaël Hertzog’s blog post introducing it](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2018/02/20/time-to-join-extended-long-term-support-for-debian-7-wheezy/).

This is a continuation of the Debian 7 [LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/), which stopped in May 2018. In the extended LTS, a subset of Debian 7 packages continue to receive support, on `amd64` and possibly `i386`. The [subset](https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/docs/supported-packages/) is determined by the sponsors of the project; to be an extended LTS sponsor, you also have to be a regular LTS sponsor. It is however possible to hitch a ride and use the extended LTS without sponsoring it, the [instructions](https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/docs/how-to-use-extended-lts/) and repository are freely available:

```
wget https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/pool/main/f/freexian-archive-keyring/freexian-archive-keyring_2018.05.29_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i freexian-archive-keyring_2018.05.29_all.deb
echo deb http://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts wheezy-lts main contrib non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extended-lts.list
echo deb http://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts wheezy-lts-kernel main | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/extended-lts.list
```

Remember to [upgrade the kernel](https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/docs/kernel-backport/) too, and set up a local package mirror.

Without becoming a sponsor, this can only be a band-aid and the resulting feeling of security will be misleading. For example, Ghostscript was dropped at the start of September...

(Freexian handles sponsorship and payments. The package maintenance is carried out by Debian developers whose time is paid for by the Extended LTS project.)

Comment: you also have to add the archived wheezy sources `deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free` to your sources.list and create a file in ´/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/no-validity-check´ with the content ´Acquire::Check-Valid-Until "0";´ (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-to-work-around-release-file-expired-problem-on-a-local-mirror)

Answer (score 1):

Officially, it looks like you have to update your official sources to archive based on this linked [closed-github issues thread](https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/issues/65) and this [official debian note](https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive) ([security link](http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/)).

The Freexian project mentioned [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489408/297048) (by [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86440/stephen-kitt)) looks like a good option but mentions it will not be supporting a lot that is in debian and it will [continue to drop select packages](https://deb.freexian.com/extended-lts/).