# How to install a few specific packages one time on Debian Wheezy (after EoL)

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, beagleboneblack

I'm using a fresh beaglebone debian 7.9 armhf image and need to do some additional setup. Despite EoL being May 2018, the apt sources have still been available until recently. They are no longer available and are yet in the archives, either, at least not [here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive).

So what is my best option for installing a few packages one time on Debian 7.9? I've attached the list below, and the best option may be different for different packages. The system has gcc and make, but not cmake... of course I can check others. It has git 1.7.10.4.

- ntp
- ftp - preferred, but not essential
- <strike>sqlite3</strike> - installed from source `sqlite-autoconf-3280000.tar.gz`
- openvpn
- libffi-dev

Perhaps it will be as easy as downloading `pkg` files and installing manually with dpkg. If so, how do I determine and find the correct versions? Maybe if someone can walk me through one example, I can figure out the rest.

```
$ uname -a
Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone79 #1 SMP Tue Oct 13 20:44:55 UTC 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

*For those who can't resist suggesting that I just upgrade: we are working on that. I have so far been unable to enable the UARTs in Stretch and even Jessie, and the documentation for that in sparse and/or contradictory. In the meantime, this would be helpful for our fairly restricted use case.*

Comment: Welcome to the Unix and Linux Stack Exchange! Please check out the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) and take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to get information on how to best post to the site. The archives are for Debian Jessie and Wheezy is in ELTS. You should reference [this wiki entry](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Extended) and you should also reference this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489394/is-there-a-way-to-get-security-updates-for-wheezy-after-eol). Likely, your beaglebone is using a Linux kernel that is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! So, I am aware that ELTS does not provide packages for this kernel/architecture. I have also seen that post. I believe it is about continuing to get security updates after EOL for all packages indefinitely. What I need to do install a few libraries one time. So the problem here is that I am only familiar with installing these sorts of packages using apt, and I need another way. I can install from source, of course, but I'm not sure how to get the source(s) necessary to replace, for example, the apt package "ntp".

Comment: I'm not familiar with beaglebone, but wouldn't the [debian wheezy archive](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/) work?
Change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to `deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib`, then `apt-get update; apt-get install ntp ftp openvpn libffi-dev`?

Comment: Yes! Seemed like the obvious thing, but when I checked last that was not up yet, or at least I could not find it. I am trying that now.

Comment: Well, it was last modified Feb 2019, so obviously it has been up. I just didn't find it. I had looked [here](https://www.debian.org/distrib/archive), which still does not have Wheezy.

Comment: @Freddy This appears to be the answer for user jmilloy. Please post it down below!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments above.

The packages can be installed from the [debian wheezy archive](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/).

Change `/etc/apt/sources.list` to

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib
```

then install the missing packages with

```
apt-get update
apt-get install ntp ftp openvpn libffi-dev
```