# Wheezy still doesn't update! 404 errors

Tags: debian, repository

I have to have the capability to rollback my internet-facing repo server to Debian Wheezy due to customer requirements.

However, when I run `apt-get update` on the rolled-back machine, I get 404 errors, as seen in the image below. Is there not an archive repo I can point at?

[image]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489394/is-there-a-way-to-get-security-updates-for-wheezy-after-eol/489408#489408 provides information you will find useful.

Answer (score 4):

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list`, remove all entries containing `wheezy-updates` and run `apt-get update` again. This repository doesn't exist any more (or never has been in the archive).

Related: [wheezy-updates on archive.debian.org returns 404 Not Found](https://serverfault.com/questions/960970/wheezy-updates-on-archive-debian-org-returns-404-not-found)

Answer (score 3):

Debian Wheezy support is ended due to end of lifetime cycle. [EOL is 31 May 2018](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/).

You should to update at least to Jessie following by [Recommendations for upgrading from Wheezy LTS to Jessie LTS](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using#Recommendations_for_upgrading_from_Wheezy_LTS_to_Jessie_LTS). EOL of Jessie is June 30 2020. Or update to another recent version of Debian.

Comment: There is a Wheezy ELTS, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489408/86440) for details.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt Thank's! Now, I will know about Wheezy ELTS.

Answer (score 0):

As root, run these commands:

```
cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.backup
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Inside the nano editor remove all lines and include:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
deb-src http://archive.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

To test the modification run:

```
apt-get update
```

Thats all! I hope it helps.