# Debian 7 end-of-life I can't install anything

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

I've a vps with debian 7 (wheezy) and I can't install any package from its repositories.
I had never used an end-of-life distribution before and I'm wondering if I can change the official repositories for continuing install some package that I will need.

Some info from my vps:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.debian.org/"
```

cat /etc/apt/*.list

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stable main non-free contrib
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

sudo apt-get update

```
Obj http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Obj http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release                         
Obj http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                                           
Obj http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                                                             
Obj http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                                                            
Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg                                                  
Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy Release                            
Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex           
Ign http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg               
Ign http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release
Ign http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Obj https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy Release.gpg      
Obj https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy Release                                    
Obj https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Sources                                                      
Obj https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main i386 Packages                         
Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-es_ES                           
Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-es    
Ign http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en    
Err http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main i386 Packages     
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:2564:a119::148:12 80]
Ign http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-es_ES
Ign http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-es
Ign http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
Err http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:9::204 80]
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-es_ES
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-es
Ign https://deb.nodesource.com wheezy/main Translation-en
W: Imposible obtener http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:2564:a119::148:12 80]

W: Imposible obtener http://security.debian.org/dists/wheezy/updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:9::204 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file so that it contains (only)

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian wheezy main
```

In particular, you should remove the `stable` line otherwise you’re liable to upgrade to Debian 10 inadvertently.

You appear to have entries in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` which might need cleaning up too.

Since you’re using `i386`, you can still benefit from the extended LTS available on Wheezy; see [Is there a way to get security updates for wheezy after EOL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/489394/86440) for details.

Comment: thanks @stephenkitt. With yours suggestion apt works again. BTW, do you recommend me to update to stretch or buster? I never do a big updated on a server

Comment: I’d recommend Stretch first. Ideally you should update to Jessie, then Stretch, because release-skipping upgrades aren’t supported. But really with a VPS I’d build a new VPS on Stretch or Buster and switch to that...

Comment: Ok. I'm thinking build a new vps, but I setting up a few services and I've much time... not to mention that something unexpected always happens