# Cannot run apt update in a Debian docker container

Tags: debian, docker, software-updates

I've got the error in the docker container [`php:7.2.20-cli`](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.2.20-cli/images/sha256-7d6b6adbee02e58094e7663f207abfeb43a304ff74c5c4f21cd2a24591d72291?context=explore)

```
E: Release file for http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 9h 1min 57s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

after running:

```
apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
```

---

Here is a full log:

```
Step 2/15 : FROM php:7.2.20-cli
 ---> 5656cb179dc0
Step 3/15 : MAINTAINER Nick Jones <nick@nicksays.co.uk>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5c856c7b88d5
Step 4/15 : RUN apt-get -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false update
 ---> Running in 145c283ee52d
Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease [49.3 kB]
Get:2 http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease [65.4 kB]
Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages [7907 kB]
Get:5 http://security-cdn.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates/main amd64 Packages [176 kB]
Reading package lists...
E: Release file for http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease is not valid yet (invalid for another 9h 1min 57s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
```

---

I assume that's not about a certain container but about Debian and repositories.

As you see I used some workaround:

[How to work around "Release file expired" problem on a local mirror](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-to-work-around-release-file-expired-problem-on-a-local-mirror)

...but it doesn't work.

So, what's wrong?

Comment: @GAD3R, no, used in the question and I mentioned this question.

Comment: @StephenKitt, yeah, datetime was an issue.

Comment: Welcome, because [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470118/153195) solve your problem.

Comment: @GAD3R, indeed. I haven't noticed it. Thanks.

Comment: @GAD3R, most people were talking about `-o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is **different time on my host in comparison with world time**.

Just synced time by using `sudo systemctl start ntpd` on CentOS host.

You may use your system approach.